# Moving "Add to cart" block before configurable product options on product page

Tags: configurable-product, layout, blocks

I'm trying to move `product.info.options.wrapper.bottom` block before `product.info.options.wrapper`.

I tried using "before" and "after" attributes in catalog.xml, but they don't work.

I tried unsetting and adding these blocks in local.xml, still no luck.

These blocks are rendered by this line in product's view.phtml file:

```
echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true)
```

(sorted = true)

How can I move these blocks?

Comment: I have similar problem but I want separate "add to cart" from "option" I want do it in view.phtml because I have custom block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured changing order of:

```
<action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
<action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
```

in `catalog.xml` was the key. Maybe it helps someone in the future.